# How to find the percentage share of two values contained in separate arrays?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need a little help to solve a problem and I wanted to see if anyone can help me:

I have an object in the following format:

```
{
   red: [
      {time: "00:00:05", value: "7"},
      {time: "00:00:10", value: "3"}],
   green: [
     {time: "00:00:05", value: "3"},
      {time: "00:00:10", value: "27"}]
}
```

What I need to do:

- Obtain the percentage share in each of the objects within "green" and "red" considering "time" and "value" as references.
- Add the share value on each "green" and "red" object.

Example of how it would look:

```
{
   red: [
      {time: "00:00:05", value: "7", share: "70%"},
      {time: "00:00:10", value: "3", share: "10%"}],
   green: [
     {time: "00:00:05", value: "3", share: "30%"},
      {time: "00:00:10", value: "27", share: "90%"}]
}
```

Can someone help me? I can not do this.

Comment: Will the object always contain two arrays or could there be more than two?

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn supposed to be red. Thanks!

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn The object always contain two arrays (red and green).
Thanks!

Comment: try this `for(key in data['red']) { data['red'][key].share = '70%'; }`

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I need to confirm if "time" is the same in both arrays because they can come in different orders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short and simple solution:

```js
const o = {
  red: [
    {time: "00:00:05",value: "7"},
    {time: "00:00:10",value: "3"}
  ],
  green: [
    {time: "00:00:05",value: "3"},
    {time: "00:00:10",value: "27"}
  ]
};
const colors = Object.keys(o);

// saves the sum of all values, for each time
const total = o[colors[0]]
  .map(x => x.time)
  .map(time => colors
    .map(c => +o[c].find(x => x.time == time).value)
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
  );
  
// adds the 'share' property
colors.forEach(c => o[c].forEach((x, i) => o[c][i].share = `${Math.floor(100*x.value/total[i])}%`))
console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this silly technique, but there is many more you can try.

I am going to group all data into one array but preserve it's `objectKey` (red, green or any other) and `indexKey` as `Symbol()`, so there won't be any name-interference.

```
let data = {
    red: [
        {time: "00:00:05", value: "7", share: "70%"},
        {time: "00:00:10", value: "3", share: "10%"}
    ],
    green: [
        {time: "00:00:05", value: "3", share: "30%"},
        {time: "00:00:10", value: "27", share: "90%"}
    ]
}

let temp = [], objectKey = Symbol("object"), indexKey = Symbol("index")
for(let object in data) {
    temp = [ ...temp, ...data[object].map((x, index) => ({ ...x, [objectKey]: object, [indexKey]: index }))]
}
```

The `temp` will look like this:

```
[
    {time: "00:00:05", value: "7", [objectKey]: "red", [indexKey]: 0},
    {time: "00:00:10", value: "3", [objectKey]: "red", [indexKey]: 1}
    {time: "00:00:05", value: "3", [objectKey]: "green", [indexKey]: 0},
    {time: "00:00:10", value: "27", [objectKey]: "green", [indexKey]: 1}
]
```

Now i will group all data by time:

```
let temp2 = temp.reduce((r, a) => (r[a.time] = r[a.time] || [], r[a.time].push(a), r), {});
```

So we get `temp2` like this:

```
{
    "00:00:05": [
        {time: "00:00:05", value: "7", [objectKey]: "red", [indexKey]: 0},
        {time: "00:00:05", value: "3", [objectKey]: "green", [indexKey]: 0},
    ],
    "00:00:10": [
        {time: "00:00:10", value: "3", [objectKey]: "red", [indexKey]: 1}
        {time: "00:00:10", value: "27", [objectKey]: "green", [indexKey]: 1}
    ]
}
```

And now i can get sum of each group, get the desired percentage and save it to correct place:

```
for(let time in temp2) {
    let sum = temp2[time].reduce((r, a) => (r + parseInt(a.value)), 0)
    temp2[time].forEach(e => (data[e[objectKey]][e[indexKey]].share = (e.value / sum * 100) + "%"))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, buddy!

I chose the other answer only for the simplicity of the code.

But thank you anyway for your time and effort to help.